# Will memcpy copy a string correctly?

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, memcpy, strcpy

I am working on implementing some low-level file writing, where the file format is specific down to each bit. I need to copy a string from an `NSString` into null-terminated string with length 16 (which is not assignable, according to Xcode). I am a total *n00b* when it comes to `c`, and want to be sure I understand this correctly. This is what I am currently doing:

```
//I have a non-null NSString called _friendly_name.
const char *string = [_friendly_name UTF8String];
//profile.friendly is a utf-8 null-terminated string
memcpy(&profile.friendly_name, &string, 16);
```

This has not yet been tested, but I want to be sure this will work. Will this provide the behavior I am expecting? Or should I be copying the string a different way (such as `strcpy`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`, but you'll have to do the bounds checking yourself and there are other errors in your code.

So, I take it you want to copy an NSString into a `char[16]` array.  You can use an `NSString` builtin method to do this, and you don't have to use `memcpy()` yourself:

```
NSString *src;
char dest[16];
NSUinteger destlen;
[src getBytes:dest
    maxLength:sizeof(dest) - 1
    usedLength:&destlen
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
    options:0
    range:NSMakeRange(0, [src length])
    remainingRange:NULL];
dest[destlen] = '\0';
```

If you want to use `memcpy()`, then you'll have to do it this way:

```
NSString *src;
char dest[16], *srcUtf8;
size_t len;

srcUtf8 = [src UTF8String];
len = strlen(srcUtf8);
if (len >= sizeof(dest))
    len = sizeof(dest) - 1;
memcpy(dest, srcUtf8, len);
dest[len] = '\0';
```

#### Errors in your code

This code has two errors in it!

```
memcpy(&profile.friendly_name, &string, 16); // Wrong!
```

First of all, `&string` is wrong.  It should be `string`, because `string` is a pointer to the string data you want to copy.  If you copy `&string`, you will get a pointer and some random bits of stack data copied instead.  In other words, you'll get garbage.

Secondly, 16 is wrong.  You can only copy 16 bytes if you know that `string` points to at least 16 bytes of data.  This will cause a segmentation fault (crash your program, hard) if `string` is less than 16 bytes the following data in memory is not readable.  It might not crash today, but maybe it will crash next week, and you'll have forgotten all about it?

It's wrong, don't pass 16 unless you know the source is at least 16 bytes long.

Comment: OK. but char friendly_name[16] will be an c-string of length 15 at most (meaning strlen(friendly_name) will <= 15 normally) .

Comment: @qPCR4vir: I don't see what `strlen(friendly_name)` has to do with anything.  We're initializing `friendly_name`, so there is no point in calling `strlen()` on it.

Comment: @qPCR4vir: About NUL-termination: go read the documentation yourself.  I'm not going to copy and paste it for you.

Comment: OK: I'm assuming now that srcUtf8 = [src UTF8String]; add a 0 at end. (than I dont see a great point in the whole Q). Anyway, if len >= sizeof(dest)) you will need to add the 0 at end (len+1) manually

Comment: @qPCR4vir: I changed the `memcpy()` version to add the `'\0'`, but on a further note we don't really know if truncation is the desired behavior.  I'm also a little confused as to why you're answering questions about Objective C if you can't find the API documentation.

Comment: This was a great answer! Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: :-) The Q was taget as C too, and I answered very "conservative", and it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

memcpy() should work fine, but strcpy() will work fine too. You just need to make sure that profile.friendly_name is big enough to hold what you're copying into it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the doc?  memcpy will work, but you pass in the number of bytes to copy.  It will copy the number of bytes you specify, irrelevant of a NULL.  strcpy you don't pass the length, it will copy bytes up to and including the first NULL.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Answer (score 0):

```
//I have a non-null NSString called _friendly_name.
const char *string = [_friendly_name UTF8String];
//profile.friendly is a utf-8 null-terminated string  : char [17] ??
memcpy(profile.friendly_name, string, 16);
profile.friendly_name[16]='\0';
```

EDIT:
Yes, exactly. Adding a `NULL` at ende. Actually it could be better to initialize to all `0` before copying. `strcpy` will not work if `_friendly_name` don't have a `'\0'` before position 16. `strncpy` will be fine.

EDIT2:

Some problem arised why we dont have all the needed information:

1- You need an NULL-terminated string of length 16 (16 character+0 as in `char var[17];`) or you need a 16 byte field terminated witch NULL as in `char var[16];`?

2- what is the desred "error" management: if the original string is larged than "16" we just truncate it, or we trow an error?

Assuming you need a field of 16 bytes and a truncate string you can use:

```
strncpy(profile.friendly_name, string, 15);
profile.friendly_name[15]='\0';
```

EDIT3:

Also... to truncate have to be made carefully: we dont want to truncate a multibyte character...

Comment: @Phil, null terminates the string.  "Strings" in C are expected to be NULL terminated.

Comment: `&string`  is wrong and `friendly_name[16]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp Thank for string !!! But how we know what exactly mean string of length 16? In c that is 16 char plus a 0, 17 byte.

Comment: I think that the field is `char friendly_name[16]`.